# How can I sum up Int and Int64?

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
tzDiff :: Int
tzDiff = 4 * 60 * 60

mySysTm :: IO Int64
mySysTm = do
    st <- getSystemTime
    pure $ systemSeconds st
```

I want to sum up these values.

```
main = do
  a1 <- mySysTm
  let res = tzDiff + mySysTm

===>

Couldn't match expected type ‘Int64’ with actual type ‘Int’
```

How can I sum them up? Without having to change the return type of `tzDiff` to be `Int64` in the function definition because it doesn't need to be Int64

I've tried this - it didn't work due to the same error:

```
  let res = (tzDiff :: Int64) + mySysTm
```

Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried this - it didn't work due to the same error:
>
> ```
> let res = (tzDiff :: Int64) + mySysTm
> ```

Because Haskell has a strongly typed type system, which means you can not implicitly convert types from one item to another. Just trying to redeclare it another type will not help either. You should use functions to convert data from one type to another.

We can for example convert an `Int` to an `Int64` with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
main = do
    a1 <- mySysTm
    let res = fromIntegral tzDiff + mySysTm
    putStrLn (show res)
```

because (+) has as type [**(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-), so it always sums up two objects of the same type, and these types are members of the `Num` typeclass. Since it knows that `mySysTm` is an `Int64`, it thus knows that the result should be an `Int64`. Since `tzDiff` is an `Int`, it thus knows that it should convert an `Int` to an `Int64`.

The `fromIntegral` is defined in the `Num` typeclass, so all types that implement the `Num` typeclass, need to provide a definition for `fromIntegral`.

Comment: how does `fromIntegral` know that I want to convert it to Int64 specifically?

Comment: @Rubashka351: because `(+)` has as type `(+) :: a -> a -> a`, so it always sums up two objects of the same type. Because it knows that `mySysTm` is an `Int64`, it thus knows that the result should be an `Int64`.

Comment: But `fromIntegral` gets executed before `+`. how does `fromIntegral` know that I want to convert it to Int64 specifically?

Comment: @Rubashka351: the type system infers that. This runs at compile time. Haskell's type system allows full type erasure. At compile time, *all* types are known. So it does not matter what is performed first.

Comment: @Rubashka351, in type inference, type information flows both from the inside to the outside *and* from the outside to the inside.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  let res = (tzDiff :: Int64) + mySysTm
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *Why not?*

Because earlier you said

```
tzDiff :: Int
```

One value can't be of two different types at the same time.

Use ***`fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`*** instead, like

```
  let res = fromIntegral tzDiff + mySysTm
```

Because the type of `+` is `(+) :: a -> a -> a`, it means that both of its operands must have the same type.

This is already evident in the code even before its compilation, let alone its execution.

`fromIntegral` is ***not*** a run-time type conversion operation. It is a function *polymorphic* in its *return type*. The *compiler* sees it, and interprets the code accordingly.